# image problem in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a color swatcher extension in my website. Previously it's working fine now a days it's not working. I check in consolve it shows

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain.com/customize-furnitures.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/210x210/9df78e…5/r/o/rockwell-accent-chair-d83c4092-7f99-44e1-9c69-eaf080aa5d60_600_1.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

[image]

Comment: did you change admin>system>configuration>web>Secure tab and check Base Media URL

Comment: admin>system>configuration>web>Secure tab  Use Secure URLs in Frontend  yes and check..

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: did you refresh the cache and index management too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`admin>system>configuration>web>Secure` tab `Use Secure URLs in Frontend` `yes`

refresh the `cache` and `index management`